# zsh: Understanding command output from wc and passing it to other commands

Tags: zsh

I'm trying to create a complex command (using shell substitutions and arithmetic expressions) and I was wondering if anyone could helpme understand the output of the `wc` command.

For instance, here are a couple of examples:

```
[11:10:33] labreu:~ $ wc -l test.txt
5 test.txt
[11:10:40] labreu:~ $ cat test.txt| wc -l
5
```

Why does the command return different values? I've tried looking at its man page, but there's nothing there about it...

Btw, I'm only asking about this because I was trying to skip x lines of a file with the following command:

```
[11:25:35] labreu:~ $ tail -n "+$(( $(wc -l test.txt)-2 ))" test.txt                       
zsh: bad math expression: operator expected at `test.txt-2...'
```

After noticing that `wc` returns `number_of_lines filename` and that using pipes (or redirection produces a different result), I managed to get what I needed by using something like this:

```
tail -n "+$(( $(wc -l<test.txt )-2 ))" test.txt

tail -n "+$(( $(cat test.txt | wc -l )-2 ))" test.txt
```

Anyway, the main question remains: why does the `wc` command returns different output when used within a pipe (or with input redirection)?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 1st method you use on command line. The 2nd method can be used when coding.

The command itself can do this for more than 1 file so it needs to tell you what amount of lines belongs to what file.

```
$ wc -l *.xml
   712 1.xml
  3055 2.xml
   464 3.xml
  3055 4.xml
```

`wc -l` itself does not distinguish between 1 file, a wildcard, or multiple files. To do it without the name I tend to use `wc -l < file.txt` so with a redirect.

The concatenate method/piped version is always 1 file so the name of the file is implied. A for loop would still imply 1 file per `wc -l` but repeating the same multiple times.